# Is there any function in G Sheet to solve the below problem?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am looking for a G Sheet formula that can help to count the occurrences of 1 and 0 in relation to each weekday.

Example: Monday has 12 occurrences and 8 are True, 4 are False. Please find the attached sheet below in the notion.

[Data Point](https://vivacious-neptune-120.notion.site/Data-Analysis-e4ab6e69578b418aa22c7f0a2d2c5c6b)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=COUNTA(IFNA(FILTER(A:A; C:C=0; A:A="Monday")))
```

or use `COUNTIFS`